# How to access attribute in method from another method, in class

Tags: python, class

I'm trying to access to an attribute in a method, from another method. They are all in one class.
It's like following.

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def meth(self):
        attr= 'yo'
        return ''

    def here(self):
        another = self.meth.attr
        return another

example = A('a')
print(example.here)
```

What I'm intending is this should print 'yo'. But it returns error sign

```
NameError: name 'yo' is not defined
```

you know, If it were not inside the class, we can access any attribute of a function from another. for example, the following code make sense.

```py
def fun1():
    fun1.var = 100
    print(fun1.var)

def fun2():
    print(fun1.var)

print(fun1.var)  >> "100"
```

And I also notice that we can access attribute in the **init** function. But I want to access attr in ohter methods.
Is there anyway to do things like this

Comment: You **must** provide a [mcve]. Your code does not produce the error you say it does, instead, it prints the method `here`. If we assume you meant `print(example.here())` it throws another error, `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'attr'` which makes sense **because you don't create an attribute `attr` anywhere**...

Comment: In any case, if you actually create an attribute in one method, another method should be able to use it. You should **definitely** not be assigning attributes to the actual function/method objects though. This all is very confused

Comment: Logically speaking, `print(fun1.var) >> "100" `would be error, right? `fun1() >> "100" `

Comment: Oops... I know that functions and methods are objects and *can* have attributes. But until you find a real use case for that (I have never seen one), my advice is to stay away from that! So unless you provide enough context, I won't help you to produce non Pythonic code. You have one object which is `self` use and set attributes on it, full stop. And best practices recomment do set initial values in `__init__`.

Comment: I copy your code results. `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'var'`. Or am I making a mistake?

Comment: @dudulu ah, true, the `fun1()` must be called first, and then `fun1.var` will be `"100"`, you are right

Comment: `attr= 'yo'` -> `self.arrt = 'yo'` `another = self.meth.attr` -> `another = self.meth(); return self.attr`  `print(example.here())` is ok. Because my English is not good, I don’t know how to explain it in English, so I can only tell you.

Comment: @dudulu Wow! It finally worked!   def here(self):   self.meth()   // this seems to be the key. After I mention 'self.meth()' to open the other method, from that moment I can use attr in that method in this method.

Comment: I don’t know how to explain this code in English, I hope you can understand later.

Comment: this is not a good idea